# Missing file in compiled selenium app

Tags: python, firefox, webdriver

I wanted to compile the short script I posted at [looking for text of an element or source of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043364/looking-for-text-of-an-element-or-source-of-current-page) so I can send it to someone who can test it on their computer.

I used the InnoIDE compiler which has worked well in the past.

**Edit! I just realized that I was in error when I said I compiled using InnoIDE - THAT utility builds the install...the compiler I use is Py2Exe... Sorry for my confusion!**

It ran and I got the compiled setup app - that ran, but when I tried to run the actual script I got an IO error:

```
IOError: [Errno 21 No such file or directory: 'C:\\Sel_Test\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver.xpi'
```

What's happening? I checked the directory, and webdriver.xpi is indeed missing!

Here's the dos window of the failed run:

[image]

Is it possible I don't have selenium/webdriver loaded properly?

Comment: If you want to compile with Selenium's webdriver, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701855/python-trouble-in-building-executable

Comment: Have you actually unzipped library.zip? That error makes it look like you're trying to reference a file which is still zipped up.